# How do you merge two tables with multiple unique indentifiers?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, merge, google-bigquery

Hey I have two tables with the same rows the first table is the main table and I want to upsert the data with new unique entries from the `_tmp_` table.

for example;

`id, text_id, last_sent, recent_sent, updated_at, date_created`

I want to merge a communicated `_tmp_` table that is created from another table into the communicated table. Only if the communicated table doesn't have an identical row id, text_id, last_sent and recent_sent

The query I'm using now is posted below but doesn't work. This query inserts all the data from the `_tmp_` table.

I have checked and both the types of the tables are the same. And I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Help much appreciated

```
MERGE
  `project.map.communicated` CURRENT_TABLE
USING
  `project.map.communicated_tmp_` NEW_OR_UPDATED
ON
  (CURRENT_TABLE.id = NEW_OR_UPDATED.id
    AND CURRENT_TABLE.text_id = NEW_OR_UPDATED.text_id
    AND CURRENT_TABLE.last_sent = NEW_OR_UPDATED.last_sent
    AND CURRENT_TABLE.recent_sent = NEW_OR_UPDATED.recent_sent)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN
INSERT
  (`id`,
    `text_id`,
    `last_sent`,
    `recent_sent`,
    `updated_at`,
    `date_created`)
VALUES
  (`id`,`text_id`,`last_sent`,`recent_sent`,`updated_at`,`date_created`)
```

Comment: If you write a query that joins the two tables using the contents of your ON clause as the join definition, does it find matching records?

Comment: @NickW If there are matching records the join works and shows the data. When there aren't matching records the join show the expected behaviour. So the statement works but in the merge it doesn't work

Comment: I'm not a GBQ expert but the INSERT statement doesn't look right (at least how it is shown in your question) as you have exactly the same strings for your column names as you do for the values e.g. `id` and `id`. I would have expected them to use different syntax , for example the values clause would just have id (with no quotes) or something similar

Comment: @NickW Thanks for the suggestion. I just found the fault. The database has null entries which they try to compare Which will result in false.

Answer (score 0):

The Merge statement uses JOIN logic to see matches. The only reason this should not work if there are rows that have NULLS in either of the fields you use for the join. Make sure to exclude the NULLS or make a composite key which works around the NULL values.